# What's wrong with my FET transfer function?

Tags: transfer-function

The following is from the book  *[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf)*, page 207.

Find the transfer function of the circuit in Fig. 6.47(a):

[image]

Suppose the voltage at  node A is \$V_x\$.

with the use of KCL at node B,

$$V_x g_{m1} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_o} = (V_x - V_{out}) s C_F - \frac{V_{out}} {R_D}$$

For \$V_x\$, with voltage divider (\$R_S\$ and \$C_F\$).

$$V_x = \frac{V_{in} - V_{out}} {R_S + 1/(s C_F)} \frac{1} {s C_F} + V_{out} $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac{(s C_F - g_m)} {s C_F R_S (g_m + 1/r_o  + 1/R_D) +  (s C_F + 1/r_o + 1/R_D)}$$

However, the arthor gave this.

$$G(S) = -g_m (R_D \parallel r_o) \frac{1- \frac{1} {g_m} C_F s} {1 + \biggr[(1 + g_m R_D) R_S + R_D \biggr] C_F s}$$

The zero is the same but the pole is different.

Comment: If you check the book's derivation, you can see that the author ignores `ro` in their derivation of the driving point impedance. The exact `Zin,0` should be `[(1 + gm * Rs) * (RD || ro) + Rs]`.

Comment: @internet Which is more accurate? Should we ignore \$r_o\$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I provided the exact expression. How can something be more accurate than the exact one?
Also, whether you can ignore `ro` or not depends on the relative values of `RD` and `ro`.
As you can see, there is the term `RD || ro`. If `RD` is much smaller than `ro`,  you can ignore `ro`.

Comment: Hopefully, from this example, you can see the usefulness of EET, which can provide more insight than the brute force method you used.

Comment: @internet I think when you use the exact \$Z_{in,0}\$, our fomula is basically the same thing, Do you agree with me? BTW, how do you know when we should ignore \$r_o\$?

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: @internet I know that when \$R_D\$ is much smaller than \$r_o\$ when we can use \$(R_D \parallel r_o) \approx R_D\$. However, the question normally won't tell us whether \$R_D\$ is much smaller than \$r_o\$. (For instance, the author never mentioned in this question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the book's derivation, you can see that the author ignores \$r_o\$ in their derivation of the driving point impedance. The exact \$Z_{in,0}\$ should be \$(1 + g_m \cdot R_s) \cdot (R_D \,||\, r_o) + R_s\$.

Also, whether you can ignore \$r_o\$ or not depends on the relative values of \$R_D\$ and \$r_o\$. As you can see, there is the term \$R_D \,||\, r_o\$. If \$R_D\$ is much smaller than \$r_o\$, you can ignore \$r_o\$. In some cases, for example, if the load \$R_D\$ is a current source which is comparable in magnitude to \$r_o\$, then you can't ignore \$r_o\$. 
Hopefully, from this example, you can see the usefulness of the Extra Element Theorem (EET), which can provide more insight than the brute force method you used.

Comment: Which acronym do you mean when you use EET?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Extra element theorem.